# Pass dynamic arguments to standalone files

Tags: labels, input, external-files, standalone

I have a bunch of `standalone` TikZ images which I use in different documents. Unfortunately, the `\node`s in these images change from one document to the next. Of course, I could simply create a copy each time I reuse a file and change the text in each `\node` accordingly. But that would turn into a hassle if I decide to change something later on. I would have to apply the changes to all copies manually.

I wonder if there is a more elegant way. Is it possible to pass arguments to a `standalone` file (e.g. via `\input`) with which to update labels dynamically?

Consider for instance this image produced by the code below. How would I go about changing the text in the node currently holding `poles of h(p0)` from one `\input` to the next?

[image]

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,decorations.markings,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]

    \def\xr{4}\def\yr{4}

    % Axes
    \draw [->] (-\xr-1,0) -- (\xr+1,0) node [above left]  {$\Re(p_0)$};
    \draw [->] (0,-\yr-0.7) -- (0,\yr+0.7) coordinate [below left = 0.3 and 0.1] (y-axis);
    \node (y-label) at ([xshift=-50]y-axis) {$\Im(p_0)$};
    \draw[ultra thin,gray] (y-axis) -- (y-label);

    % Matsubara frequencies
    \foreach \n in {-\yr,...,-1,1,2,...,\yr}{%
        \draw[fill] (0,\n) circle (1pt) node [right] {$i \omega_{_{\n}}$};}
    \draw[fill] (0,0) circle (1pt) node [above right] {0};

    % Contour line
    \draw[DarkBlue,decoration={markings,mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 0.28 with \arrow{>}},postaction={decorate}] (1,-\yr) -- (1,\yr) node [below right] {$C$} arc (0:180:1) (-1,\yr) -- (-1,-\yr) arc (180:360:1);

    % Poles
    \node (poles) at (3,1.5) {poles of $h(p_0)$};
    \draw[fill]
    (2.5,3) coordinate [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=left:$p_1$] (p1)
    (2,-2) coordinate [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$p_2$] (p2)
    (-3,2) coordinate [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=above:$p_3$] (p3)
    (-2.5,-2.5) coordinate [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=above:$p_4$] (p4);
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \draw[ultra thin,gray]
        (poles) -- (p1)
        (poles) -- (p2)
        (poles.west) -- (p3)
        (poles) -- (p4);
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not perfectly clear what you mean by 'label'. Maybe `\label` or `\caption` inside `figure` environments? Or `tick labels` or the text of `\node` in TikZ? Could you provide an example image file?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly possible. I do this myself. Is that all you wanted to know? I can only presume so as you've not provided any example you want help adapting. However, it hardly seems worth writing an answer just to say this. The way I do it is to pass the values to Ti*k*Z from the including file. More specifically, I have macros in a class file which are used in the document and which pass the values to Ti*k*Z when `\input`ting the `standalone` images.

Comment: @FelixEmanuel Excuse my lack of clarity. I'm talking about the contents of `\node`s in TikZ images (nothing to do with `\caption` or `\label`). I'll add an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two possible solutions.

I recommend solution 1 for many parameters and solution 2 for only a few, because they must be passed in the right order (the limit are 9 parameters).

1. You can (re)set Parameters with `\renewcommand{\tikzParameter}{text}` between several input-calls and insert `\tikzParameter` in the tikzfile.

**Main.tex**

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,decorations.markings,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\tikzParameter}{poles of $h(p_0)$}
    \input{tikzfile}

    \renewcommand{\tikzParameter}{Another Text}
    \input{tikzfile}
\end{document}
```

tikzfile.tex contains all content of the question inside the `tikzpicture` environment with an additional `\tikzParameter` at the right place:

**tikzfile.tex (shortversion):**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    % ...
    % Poles
    \node (poles) at (3,1.5) {\tikzParameter};
    % ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: tikzpicture with two configurations]

2. You could define the whole tikzpicture inside a `\newcommand{\tikzpic}[<number of parameters>]{...}` and insert #1 ... #9 for the parameters.

**Main.tex**

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,decorations.markings,positioning}

\input{tikzfile}

\begin{document}
    \tikzpic{poles}
    \tikzpic{Another Text}
\end{document}
```

tikzfile.tex contains all content of the question inside the `tikzpicture` environment with the newcommand and #1:

**tikzfile.tex (shortversion)**

```
\newcommand{\tikzpic}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    % ...
    % Poles
    \node (poles) at (3,1.5) {#1};
    % ...
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Comment: Damn, why didn't I think of this. Great answer! I especially like method 1.